# When connecting 2 external 2 TB Hard Drives in Windows it does not recognize one of them

Tags: windows, hard-drive

However whenever I boot into a Linux Distro and when I connect my external Hard Drive and I am able to see both my external hard drives, what could be the reason for Windows not showing me my 2nd External 2 TB Hard Drive?

Comment: Do you just not see an expected drive letter?  Do both drives appear underneath "Disk Management" under "Computer Management"?

Comment: Both the drives appear beneath computer management, this issue is not restricted my PC its the same on my friends PC.

Comment: I have both External's from WD, so when I connect there is this virtual disc drive that it mounts to install its software, I get both, one for each external, but not my HDD.

Comment: If you connect only the 2nd drive, is it then visible to Windows?

Comment: No it's not if I connect both of them I can see one but not the other, but if I connect both of them individually by not connecting the other both of them are recognised by windows.

Comment: Sorry I miss read your comment, yes if I only connect my second HDD it is visible on my computer

Answer (score 1):

As both drives appear under Computer Management, you should just need to right-click the one that isn't yet assigned a drive letter, then select "Change Drive Letter and Paths", then "Add..." - and assign it a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

What filesystem and partitiontable is on the drive? if it does not show under windows, but does under linux this is a good sign for a non ntfs or fat drive, or even one with a special partition table not recognized by windows.

you can check the partition table type table with `parted` under linux

```
 parted /dev/sdx print
```

choose your drives id here (not partition id).

the filesystems are not 100% correct, but their type should also give you a clue.

Comment: They both are on NTFS that's not a problem, because if I disconnect the hdd which windows recognises and reconnect the one which wasn't detected by windows I can see my HDD show up again.